# powershell Import module not working properly

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0

How to verify whether module (Import module ) command is imported module successfully in C# ? I have my own custom powershell, which is imported in Windows powershell.I have written C# code which will import the my custom powershell into windows powershell, When I try to execute custom powershell command from code it is not returning any result whereas when i execute same command from windows powershell (By importing module and writing a custom powershell command) it is working. I am using following code

```
InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "ABCD" });
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
initial.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true;
runspace.Open();
RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new  RunspaceInvoke(runspace); 
runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;      
string script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Export-Pipeline-Script.txt");
ps.AddScript(script);
ps.Invoke();
ps.Commands.Clear();
ps.AddCommand("Test2");
Collection<PSObject> results1 = ps.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject outputItem in results1)
{
    if (outputItem != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(outputItem.ToString());
    }
}
```

In AddCommand the Test2 is a function in which I have written the custom powershell command. In the above code results1 always written count as "0" whereas when I changed the custom powershell command to windows powershell command like Get-Process, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that worked for me. I created a PS module and a custom PS script and used them in your C# code. this might give you some clue as to how you can make yours work.

**C:\Temp\PowerShell.Module.psm1**
[image]

here is the custom powerhell. **C:\Temp\PS\GetProc.ps1**

[image]

worked with this code:

```
InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] { @"C:\Temp\PowerShell.Module.psm1" });
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
initial.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true;
runspace.Open();
RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new  RunspaceInvoke(runspace); 
runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;      
string script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\Export-Pipeline-Script.txt");
ps.AddScript(script);
ps.Invoke();
ps.Commands.Clear();
ps.AddCommand("GetProc");
Collection<PSObject> results1 = ps.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject outputItem in results1)
{
    if (outputItem != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(outputItem.ToString());
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Are you using screenshots of code just to avoid lazy copying? Text is always better.

Comment: I used screenshots for my own example in that OP didn't give enough information about his PS code. so I intended my example to be just an illustrated alternative. this also makes OP avoid lazy copying too.